# Adding elements to an array in nested scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I'm feeling stupid but i dont find what is the problem here

```
var images = [];

angular.forEach($scope.flow.images.files, function (flowFile, i) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function (event) {
        var uri = event.target.result;
        images.push(uri);
        console.log(images.length); // First iteration length = 1, second iteration length = 2 
    };

    console.log(images.length); // Always shows 0
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(flowFile.file);

});
```

Can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. The log of `images.length` occurs **before the `fileReader.onload` function is fired** despite it sequentially occurring after, hence the discrepancies in the content of the `images` array.

To circumvent this behaviour and [avoid callback hell](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/promisesandchaininginangularjs-141027044455-conversion-gate02/95/promises-and-chaining-in-angularjs-into-callback-hell-and-back-again-17-638.jpg?cb=1414385382), take a look at this [tutorial on Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) in JavaScript.